# getUrl without opening window AS2

Tags: flash, url, actionscript, actionscript-2

How do you call a URL from ActionScript 2 without opening a new window ? I've tried "getUrl" and various methods of "LoadVars".

Comment: Are you talking about redirection to another url? Or, do you mean to fetch data from the url?

Comment: I just want to call a method on my service which increments a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var loader = new LoadVars();
loader.load("http://example.com/yourscript");
```